# Scrollable table with header and first 3 columns fixed

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with fixed header but the header and the body are not aligned properly. The no.of columns is more than 25. If I remove `"display:block"`, the header is not fixed.

Here is my Code

```
 <table width="100%" style="font-size:13px" id="data" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="5" border="2" class="scrollTable">
            <thead style="background:#e2e2e2" align="center" class="fixedHeader">
                <tr>
                    <th>Header 1</th>
                    <th>Header 2</th>
                    <th>Header 3</th>
                    <th>Header 4</th>
                    <th>Header 5</th>
                    <th>Header 6</th>
                    <th>Header 7</th>
                    <th>Header 8</th>
                    <th>Header 9</th>
                    <th>Header 10</th>
                    <th>Header 11</th>
                    <th>Header 12</th>
                    <th>Header 13</th>
                    <th>Header 14</th>
                    <th>Header 15</th>
                    <th>Header 16</th>
                    <th>Header 17</th>
                    <th>Header 18</th>
                    <th>Header 19</th>
                    <th>Header 20</th>
                    <th>Header 21</th>
                    <th>Header 22</th>
                    <th>Header 23</th>
                    <th>Header 24</th>
                    <th>Header 25</th>
                    <th>Header 26</th>
                    <th>Header 27</th>
                    <th>Header 28</th>
                    <th>Header 29</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="background:#f2f2f2;" align="center"   class="scrollContent">
               <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                                 <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                               <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                               <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                               <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                               <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                                 <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                                   <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>
                              <tr>
                    <td>Data 1</td>
                    <td>Data 2</td>
                    <td>Data 3</td>
                    <td>Data 4</td>
                    <td>Data 5</td>
                    <td>Data 6</td>
                    <td>Data 7</td>
                    <td>Data 8</td>
                    <td>Data 9</td>
                    <td>Data 10</td>
                    <td>Data 11</td>
                    <td>Data 12</td>
                    <td>Data 13</td>
                    <td>Data 14</td>
                    <td>Data 15</td>
                    <td>Data 16</td>
                    <td>Data 17</td>
                    <td>Data 18</td>
                    <td>Data 19</td>
                    <td>Data 20</td>
                    <td>Data 21</td>
                    <td>Data 22</td>
                    <td>Data 23</td>
                    <td>Data 24</td>
                    <td>Data 25</td>
                    <td>Data 26</td>
                    <td>Data 27</td>
                    <td>Data 28</td>
                    <td>Data 29</td>
               </tr>                   
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The corresponding css for this code is here

```
   div.tableContainer {
clear: both;
height: 360px;
overflow: auto;
width: 1024px
    }    

     /* define width of table. Add 16px to width for scrollbar.           */

    html>body div.tableContainer table {
width: 1024px
     }

    html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
display: block
     }


    thead.fixedHeader th {
background: #C96;
border-left: 1px solid #EB8;
border-right: 1px solid #B74;
border-top: 1px solid #EB8;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 4px 3px;
text-align: center
    }
    thead.fixedHeader {
color: #000;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
width: 100%;
}
    html>body tbody.scrollContent {
display: block;
height: 262px;
overflow: auto;
width:100%;
    }
    tbody.scrollContent td, tbody.scrollContent tr.normalRow td {
background: #FFF;
border-bottom: none;
border-left: none;
border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
    }
    tbody.scrollContent tr.alternateRow td {
background: #EEE;
border-bottom: none;
border-left: none;
border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
    }
   html>body thead.fixedHeader th {
width: 60px
    }
    html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th {
width: 140px
    }
    html>body thead.fixedHeader th + th + th {
width: 360px
    }

    html>body tbody.scrollContent td {
width: 60px
    }
    html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td {
width: 140px
    }
    html>body tbody.scrollContent td + td + td {
width: 360px
    }
```

I need the first 3 columns and header of the table to be fixed and rest of the columns scrollable. Help me out

Answer (score 0):

I've put your code on jsfiddle for better visibility: http://jsfiddle.net/

If I understand you correctly, you will have to work with at least two tables.

```
<table>
    <tr class="fixed">
        <th>column 1, row 1</th>
        <th>column 1, row 2</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="fixed">
        <td>column 2, row 1</td>
        <td>column 2, row 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="fixed">
        <td>column 3, row 1</td>
        <td>column 3, row 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="fixed">
        <td>column 4, row 1</td>
        <td>column 4, row 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table class="scrollable">
                <tr>
                    [rest of what you would have put in your main table]
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

To make the header and the first three columns after the header sticky you will have to do the following two steps with javascript (e.g. with jquery):

1. duplicate everything that has the class "fixed" into a new DOM-element that looks exactly as the original content on the site
2. whenever the user scrolls check if the header starts to move out of screen, then make that previously made content visible and attach it to the top of the screen.

That might seem like a lot at first, but it's no magic. Here's additional resources to get you started:

Make something stick to the top of the page:

```
.element {position: fixed; top: 0;}
```

- [jquery clone() -> put content of your site into a new DOM-element](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)
- [jquery scroll() -> check if the user scrolls and then act to it](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Everything else, I am sure, you can find out! Good luck!

Comment: Yeah...The entire header and the first 3 columns of the body segment should be fixed to the screen so that "the header and the first 3 columns of the body" are always visible to the user.Will be much helpful if you can provide with some javascript or jquery.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem. Some of your CSS was disrupting the size of your content cells, and you needed to adjust for the size of the scrollbar by adding some `padding-right: 17px;` on the header row.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X6Ck5/

Comment: If the content is different then the alignment breaks..moreover i need my first 3 columns to be fixed as well.